# Twilio.Initialize is not working in xamrin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, twilio

Anyone have an idea for Twilio voice call, I have already added Twilio and Twilio Client

```
Twilio.Initialize is not available in xamrin android
```

Comment: Hey Jasmin, your question is not clear. Where did you see that message about Twilio Initialize not being available? What tutorial are you trying to follow?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/11/twilio-client-for-xamarin-part-3-android.html

Comment: Hi @JasminSojitra, did you able to achieve this. I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please you can try with the below code.

```
TwilioClient.Android.Twilio.Initialize (this.ApplicationContext, this);
```